# Fixing Two key events on single key press by xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap, disk-usage, xev

I'm using a Dell Latitude D620. Whenever I press the space key, the down arrow key is also triggered to perform its action. Here is the log:

```
KeyPress event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
             root 0x10c, subw 0x0, time 2248017, (70,-9), root:(76,39),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x10c, subw 0x0, time 2248018, (70,-9), root:(76,39),
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x10c, subw 0x0, time 2248083, (70,-9), root:(76,39),
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x10c, subw 0x0, time 2248085, (70,-9), root:(76,39),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ClientMessage event, serial 33, synthetic YES, window 0x3200001,
    message_type 0x157 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x155 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

The above log is for a single press+release of the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> key. I would like to know how to fix that. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the comment by the OP, it sounds like this was a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to your home directory.

```
cd ~
```

- Create/Open the file `.Xmodmap`.

```
vim .Xmodmap
```

- Add the following lines.

```
keycode 65 = space
keycode 116 = Down
```

- Log out and log back in.
- The auto-repeat might be missing. To fix it, run:

```
xset r 66
```

- To run it every time you log in, add it to the bottom of the file: `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50x11-common_determine-startup`.

**Note:** I've assumed that space has the keycode 65 and Down key has 116.

Comment: Not solved. Few Questions: what xset doing? do I have to run it every time, or set it with bash profile? I've added the last code /etc/.. to the end of the file I created in first step. Not fixed.

Comment: Nope! You've to open the `/etc/X11.....` file and add the `xset r 66` to the bottom of that file.

Comment: sadly, my laptop completely don't accept any keys now. Even don't allows into BIOS. Hence, I'm waiting until it fixed.